# How to send small and large image as a push notification in android using GCM

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have written a php code to send a push notification to android mobile using GCM server. Its working fine. Now I want to send large and small image as a push notification. How can I do that Here is my code.

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/github-512.png',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Just send your `image link` in `push notification` and load it in your receiver.

Comment: Yeah... I have tried that.. But its not woking.. this is my image link     `'largeIcon' => 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-logotypes/512/github-512.png'`

Comment: Are you getting this link in your receiver ? if yes then show your receiver.

Comment: Receiver??.. Sorry.. I can't get you..?

Comment: @VadivelMurugan check how to load image from the server or you can first download the image than show.it's work

Comment: i suggest you to go through this you will understand everything it is what you want. [http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/)

I'm using this and you would get much more in this and your large image and small image problem can be solved from here and it's totally free of cost . I hope it would help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the image specified in the 'largeIcon' parameter as a bitmap and set it in the notification. Here is an example of how it is done with Glide Image loading library.

In your GCMListener service's onMessageReceived do the following

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String largeIconUrl = data.getString("largeIcon"); // the way you obtain this may differ
    Bitmap largeBitmap = null;
    try {
       largeBitmap = Glide
                      .with(this)
                      .load(largeIconUrl)
                      .asBitmap()
                      .into(100, 100) // Width and height
                      .get();
    } catch (Exception ex){
        // image download from the url failed
    }

    if(largeBitmap != null){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION); 
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) 
                                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) 
                                                            .setContentTitle("Your title goes here") 
                                                            .setContentText("Your description goes here") 
                                                            .setAutoCancel(true) 
                                                            .setSound(defaultSoundUri) 
                                                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) 
                                                            .setLargeIcon(largeBitmap); 

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build()); 
    }
}
```